# Prove that f ◦ g = 0 ⇔ g ◦ f = 0 if f,g are normal endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a euclidean/unitary $\mathbb{K}$-vectorspace with dim($V$)$<\infty$ 
and be $f,g$ normal endomorphisms of $V$.

How can I prove that $f \circ g = 0 \Leftrightarrow g \circ f = 0$?

Comment: You can *prove*, not *proof* (to proof means to paint with tar a boat so as to make it waterproof...)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $f\circ g=0$ iff $\mathrm{im}\,g\subseteq\ker f$.
- For a normal operator $T$, $\ker T=\ker T^*$ and $\mathrm{im}\,T=\mathrm{im}\,T^*$.